# initialization and deletion of Cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm new to javascript and stuck with the following problem with cookies

**Problem**

The cookie value in the following problem is a name.

I'm trying to display the user's name from the cookie. When the page is opened, if there is a cookie value, then the cookie value must be displayed with appropriate greeting. But if there is no cookie value when the page is opened, a prompt box must pop up asking the name of the user. If the name(cookie value) of the user is displayed wrongly on the page, for instance John opens the page and the name displayed is Paul, then he must click on "click here if You are not Paul" and the cookie must be deleted and John must see a prompt box asking for his name. Then the new cookie value must be whatever John enters in the prompt box

**Code**

The greetings part is working perfectly. I have the following code.FYI, I'm testing this on a website, not local machine.

```
<script>
var now = new Date();
var hours = now.getHours();
var name, greeting, count,a;
if(hours < 12)
{
    greeting = "Good Morning";
}
else
{
    if(hours < 18)
    {
        greeting = "Good Afternoon";
    }
    else
    {
        greeting = "Good Evening";
    }
}
if(document.cookie)
{
    var newCookie = document.cookie;
    var cookieVals = newCookie.split("=");
    name = cookieVals[1];
}
else 
{
    name = window.prompt("Please enter your name","name");
    document.cookie = "name=" + name;
}
a = greeting + " " +name + ", Welcome to Survey Page! </h1>" + "<a href = '#' onClick='return false;' onMouseDown='wrongPerson()'> " +"Click here if you are not " + name + "</a>";
function wrongPerson()
{
    document.cookie= "name=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC";
    location.reload();
}
<p><span id="verify"></span></p>
<script>document.getElementById("verify").innerHTML = a;</script>
```

**Output**

I'm getting the following output

Good Evening 74bec77-148138c40e3-42e9b6fa-5; _ga, Welcome to Survey Page! Click here if you are not 74bec77-148138c40e3-42e9b6fa-5; _ga

Nothing happens when I reload the page or when I click on the link "Click here if you are not 74bec77-148138c40e3-42e9b6fa-5; _ga".

Can someone enlighten me on this?

Comment: I highly recommend using jQuery cookie plugin: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript :

```
if(document.cookie)
{
    var newCookie = document.cookie;
    var cookieVals = newCookie.split("=");
    name = cookieVals[1];
}
```

checks that is there anything in the cookie and if it is then it will not ask for new name. When the user clicks on I am not ... then The function `wrongPerson()` sets the cookie to "name=........" which when compare at starting by your `if` will always return true because

> In javascript non zero values are `TRUE`

So it will think that a user is present. If you will make the function `wrongPerson()` make the cookie `0` or `""` , then the `if` will get `FALSE` and the statement (used to ask for name) will get executed.

**Fixed** Function:

```
function wrongPerson()
{
    document.cookie= "";
    location.reload();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create / Call functions it is much easier to understand. [source](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>

function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = cname+"="+cvalue+"; "+expires;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) != -1) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function checkCookie() {
    var user=getCookie("username");
    if (user != "") {
        alert("Welcome again " + user);
    } else {
       user = prompt("Please enter your name:","");
       if (user != "" && user != null) {
           setCookie("username", user, 30);
       }
    }
}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="checkCookie()">
</body>
</html>
```